# using $(this) doesn't reference anchor

Tags: jquery

I have this code here on some links:

```
<a href="#" onclick="addToBox('PNSM2'); return false"><i class="fa fa-suitcase"></i><sup><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></sup></a>

<a href="#" onclick="addToBox('PNSM3'); return false"><i class="fa fa-suitcase"></i><sup><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></sup></a>

function addToBox(p){

  $(this).addClass('success').html('Added.');updateQuoteBox();

}
```

The problem is when i click on the link it does nothing. The text or class don't change. Shouldn't it change the text/class of the link that was clicked? Am i missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass in the object on your onclick event:

```
<a href="#" onclick="addToBox(this, 'PNSM2'); return false"><i class="fa fa suitcase"></i><sup><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></sup></a>
<a href="#" onclick="addToBox(this, 'PNSM3'); return false"><i class="fa fa-suitcase"></i><sup><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></sup></a>

function addToBox(obj, text){
    $(obj).addClass('success').html('Added.');
    updateQuoteBox();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`this`, in your function, references the `window` object. A good way to re-write your code is to use data attributes and to not use inline JavaScript:

```
<a href="#" data-p="PNSM2"><i class="fa fa-suitcase"></i><sup><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></sup></a>
<a href="#" data-p="PNSM3"><i class="fa fa-suitcase"></i><sup><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></sup></a>

$(function() {
    $('a[data-p]').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).addClass('success').html('Added.');
        updateQuoteBox();//What does this function do?
        //Use $(this).data('p') to get the value of p
    });
});
```

```js
    $(function() {
        $('a[data-p]').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).addClass('success').html('Added.');
        });
    });
```

```css
.success {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-p="PNSM2">First</a>
<a href="#" data-p="PNSM3">Second</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work that way. You got to send the `event` and get the target from the event:

```
<a href="#" onclick="addToBox(event, 'PNSM2'); return false">

function addToBox(event, p){

    $(event.target).addClass('success').html('Added.');updateQuoteBox();

}
```

Comment: @AmmarCSE because a `function` defined that way does belong to window, so that is why `this`is the the window object. Still you could do ``<a href="#" onclick="console.log(this)"/>I am the a tag in `this` case</a>``

Answer (score 0):

Just use data-attributes or different id's or classes for get the element and then call addclass method like :
`<a href="#" id="PNSM2">....</a>
<a href="#" id="PNSM3">...</a>`

`$('#PNSM2').something<br>
$('#PNSM3').something<br>`
   
OR
`<a href="#" class="PNSM2">....</a>
<a href="#" class="PNSM3">...</a>`

`$('.PNSM2').something
$('.PNSM3').something`